# Flutter: TextFormField focus if no data

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I have a `TextFormField` as follows

```
TextFormField(
    readOnly: true,
    validator: (v) => (v.isEmpty) ? "Required" : null,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    controller: sportCenterEditingController,
    decoration: ...,
    onTap: () async {
        var t = showModalAndReturnData();    
        if (t != null) 
            sportCenterEditingController.text = sportCenters[i].name;
    }),
```

and even when `t == null` it goes to focus mode

[image]

how can I avoid that? If no data, I would like that it keeps to be unfocused

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
sportCenterEditingController.clear();
```

Comment: it doesn't work, same behaviour